# How to catch and send the 'return' values of a function executed remotely in Python

Tags: python-3.x, exec, python-sockets

I am trying to develop a client/server script to execute some Python code on a remote computer (for the sake or controlling some devices remotely.)

I am able to communicate and execute commands remotely (the dummy commands I listed on the server side.)

I have been trying to send feedback on the output of the commands sent to the server back to the client, but it seems I am unable to catch it:

```
Test client sending packets to IP 131.169.33.198, via port 5004

b'Dummy.one(1,2)'
b'Dummy.two(1)'
b'Dummy.three(1,2)'
```

so I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to catch the return values of the function executed remotely in order to send it back to the client. So far, when the server catches the three commands I send and executes them, I get the following result from `print(command)`:

```
Test server listening on port 5004

None
None
None
```

I am providing with my MWE scripts below for both server and client - they should execute without exceptions.

One last question would be on how to efficiently close the ports before exiting the server, so that I do not find error messages regarding the port status.

Thanks in advance

**Server script**

```
# Server code 

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 20 11:40:03 2022

@author: strelok
"""

from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
import os
import time

class Dummy:
    
    def one(arg1,arg2):
        a = f"I got {arg1} and {arg2}"
        return a

    def two(arg1):
        a = f"I got {arg1}"
        # print(a)
        return a
        
    def three(arg1,arg2):
        a = arg1 + arg2
        # print(f"the answer is {a}")
        return a

PORT_NUMBER = 5004
SIZE = 1024

hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)   
    command = exec(str(data, encoding = 'utf-8'))
    print(command)
    # mySocket.send(bytes(command))
     

sys.exit()
```

**Client script**

```
# Client code
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 20 11:34:32 2022

@author: strelok
"""

import sys
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import time

def send_command(text):
        message = bytes(text, encoding = 'utf-8')
        print(message)
        mySocket.send(message)
        time.sleep(.5)
        

SERVER_IP   = '131.169.33.198'
PORT_NUMBER = 5004
SIZE = 1024
print ("Test client sending packets to IP {0}, via port {1}\n".format(SERVER_IP, PORT_NUMBER))

mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
mySocket.connect((SERVER_IP,PORT_NUMBER))

# Sending the commands to be executed remotely

send_command("Dummy.one(1,2)")
send_command("Dummy.two(1)")    
send_command("Dummy.three(1,2)")

sys.exit()
```

Comment: There is nothing in your client code to receive a response back (the return value) and to print it. For your last question- you could use _\_exit_\_ and add a line to close the socket or you could enclose the entire block in a while True loop and add a finally: socket.close()

Comment: @mr_mooo_cow, and regarding how to catch the return value in the server itself?

Comment: Check out this page: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/#echo-client-and-server it has a much better structure and the examples exchange messages (in your case return values) back and forth. It also opens the socket using _with_ so that you don't have to call close()